# Flash in hidden div, load only when div is shown

Tags: jquery, flash

I have a flash file that is in a div that is hidden when the page is loaded with the css property `display:none`. The div with the flash content is then shown at a later stage through javascript.

When will the flash file load? Ideally, I only want it to load when the div is shown.

Comment: You might consider only loading the flash file with JS then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i would do is load the flash file only if the div is visible, what you can also do is create a `<noscript>` tag around the flash file so when javascript is disabled it will still display.

```
if($(div).is(":visible")){

    $(this).load("flash.swf");

}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. The thing is I don't want it to load if the user doesn't have javascript. It's sort of just an extra feature. (A konami code, to be specific.)

Comment: If the user doesn't have javascript enabled, the flash file won't load. This is what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Yes, and the file won't load until the javascript function is called to show that div.